# Enable ADB Debugging on Android Phone with broken/disabled screen

Tags: android, debug, adb

Dropped my Nexus 6 this morning and now the screen is barely legible and touch doesn't work.  Want to remote in with ADB to get what I need off the device;  however when I connect it to my laptop I get a prompt to allow debugging (OK/Cancel); however I can't click OK because the screen doesn't work. If I connect an OTG adapter and a dongle for a mouse, I can move a cursor around the screen and click on icons.

Problem is I can't have both connected at the same time.  I tried various configurations through a powered USB hub but none worked.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

1) Connected the Android Phone to a keyboard via Bluetooth
2) Connect the USB cable, launch adb debugging (see below)
3) "Enable USB Debugging" prompt will appear on the device, right arrow + enter on the keyboard to accept
4) Install the Vysor Chrome plugin to connect to your device (see below)

ADB debugging:
..\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
ZXXXXXFN      unauthorized

-->after accepting adb debugging:
..\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
ZXXXXXFN      device

Install Vysor:
https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/fully-control-your-android-device-from-any-computer-0164097/

Thanks to [Vlady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1568530/vladyslav-matviienko) who posted some useful hints when I originally posted this question on StackOverflow

Comment: No! This is a lie for broken black screens! If your device has never authorised a PC you want to use Vysor or even scrcpy on, it will never work! Unless you master blindly controlling with Keyboards! You can connect the USB mouse but cant allow any device to see the screen if lockscreen was enabled. Also, you can not connect any BT enabled device if it wasn't connected before.